# CircuiTikZ: Redefine 'open nodes fill' key to 'fill=none' (so that open-circuit terminals are not filled)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, circuitikz

## Problem description

As described in the "Terminal shapes" section (currently section 4.12) of the [`circuitikz` manual](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf), the "open circuit" versions of bipole nodes are

> [...] by default filled with the color specified by the key `open nodes fill` (by default `white`), but you can override locally it [sic] with
> the `fill` parameter.

This default is not always desirable, specifically in situations where the background color itself is not white, such as illustrated in the MWE below.

## Desired solution

I would like to not fill open circuit terminals at all (but instead only draw their contour). My hope is to use the `fill=none` option to redefine the key `open nodes fill` accordingly for the entire document, but I am - undoubtedly due to my only vague understanding of TikZ styles and PGF keys - not sure how to achieve this.

## Minimal working example

Save to `test.tex` and compile via `pdflatex test`, then see `TODO` comments for things I already tried unsuccessfully.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}%

% Background color
\usepackage{pagecolor}% 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text,backgrounds}%

\usepackage{circuitikz}%
\standaloneenv{circuitikz}% Correct image cropping with circuitikz & standalone

%%%% TODO: Some things I tried that do NOT work:
%\tikzset{open nodes fill/.style={none}}
%\tikzset{open nodes/.style={fill=none}}
%\tikzstyle{open nodes fill}=[none]

\begin{document}%

\begin{circuitikz}[background rectangle/.style={fill=gray}, show background rectangle]%
%%%%% TODO: Some alternatives that I tried that do NOT work:
%\begin{circuitikz}[background rectangle/.style={fill=gray}, show background rectangle, open nodes/.style={fill=none}]%
%\begin{circuitikz}[background rectangle/.style={fill=gray}, show background rectangle, open nodes fill/.style={none}]%
%\begin{circuitikz}[background rectangle/.style={fill=gray}, show background rectangle, open nodes fill/.style={fill=none}]%

  % Test: Resistor with two open circuit ends that I'd like to not be filled
  \draw (0,0) to[short, o-o, R] (3,0);%
  
  %%%%% TODO: Not even a local change seems to work:
  %\draw (0,0) to[short, o-o, R, fill=none] (3,0);%

\end{circuitikz}%

\end{document}%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all**: [you found a bug](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/559), in the sense that the parameter `open poles opacity` (described in [section 6.1.1](http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf#dc) of the manual) was *not* working as expected when a fill color was defined (duh! Thanks).

The fix will soon be released, but for now, you can use the "git" version as explained here: https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/.

#### Now the answer, once the bug is fixed

Basically, you probably don't want it. But let's see what happens. To explain it, I reduced a bit your MWE to this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}%
\usepackage{pagecolor}%
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text,backgrounds}%
\usepackage{circuitikz}%
\begin{document}%

\colorlet{mybgcolor}{cyan!20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=mybgcolor},
    show background rectangle]%
    \draw (0,0) to[R, o-*,] (3,0);%
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}%
```

which results in:

[image]

Notice that you should *not* write `to[short, R]`: one component can be a resistor or a short circuit, not both. Sometimes it works, but it can explode in interesting ways...

To have transparent poles, you can use the key `poles/open fill opacity`. But the result is not what you probably want:

```
\ctikzset{poles/open fill opacity=0.0}
\draw (0,0) to[R, o-*,] (3,0);
```

[image]

What happened? In Ti*k*Z paths, nodes are drawn *after* the path; you can see that it is exactly the same for normal Ti*k*Z shapes:

```
\ctikzset{poles/open fill opacity=0.0}
\draw (0,1) node[circle,draw,fill=white,fill opacity=0]{} 
   -- (3,1)  node[circle,draw,fill]{};
\draw (0,0) to[R, o-*,] (3,0);
```

[image]

...and this is the reason *why* poles override opacity, normally, so that they are always filled.

#### Solution 1: Placing the nodes first

You can have a satisfactory solution [(since v1.2.1, that is)](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/418) by placing the nodes, and after that *using the node name* to connect a component:

```
\ctikzset{poles/open fill opacity=0.0}
\node [ocirc](A) at (0,0){}; \node[circ](B) at (3,0){};
\draw (A) to[R, o-*,] (B);
```

[image]

This works because now that the nodes are there *before* the path is set, Ti*k*Z uses the "border anchors" of the nodes to connect. Or you can place the poles after the component, using the explicit anchors `(A.west)`, `(A.east)`, etc.

#### Solution 2: Match fill color to background color

All of this becomes much more complex if there are crossing wires on the poles, so the best solution for normal usage is to *let the open poles be filled*, and just use a `\colorlet` as in the example for the background color and fill with that:

```
\ctikzset{open poles fill=mybgcolor}
\draw (0,0) to[R, o-*] (3,0);
```

[image]

(Please notice that for this last option, you do not need to use the fixed version of `circuitikz`, the bug was related only to the opacity!)

Comment: Thanks, this is excellent! Yes, the `to[short, R]` was actually unintended (I added the resistor only on second thought to better illustrate this being a question related to CircuiTikZ, specifically, and forgot to remove the `[short]` option. Thanks for the credits on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/559)! The suggested solution of placing the nodes first probably works best for me (since I need to accommodate cases in which the background color needs to remain flexible; that's why the last proposed solution does not work in my case).

Comment: A quick follow-up question regarding "Workaround 1" (as I have taken the liberty to now name it above), ie, setting the open nodes fill opacity to 0, placing the nodes first, and then connecting to their .east/.west: I tried to implement this on my system (yes, CircuiTikZ is v1.3.0), but I still get non-transparent open nodes. I presume this is due to the bug you described above that is now fixed - is that correct?

Comment: @FlorianH. Yes, that's the bug I cited. You can use/check the new version by downloading http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzgit.sty , saving it in the same directory as your main LaTeX file, and changing `\usepackage{circuitikz}` into `\usepackage{circuitikzgit}`. (A recent version is 1.3.8, I'll release 1.4.0 soon)

Comment: Release `1.3.9` is on its way to CTAN with the fix.